# How to order by multiple columns in Spring data JPA query with calculation in order by?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to add the following query to the JPA repository @Query

```
"select st from Strategy st where st.unId= ?1 order by ( st.totalMargin / st.totalRevenue ) desc"
```

However, this query does not parse due to the "(" brackets in the query.

```
The error thrown while bean initialization is 
Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: "Encountered "(" at
```

Is there any way this can be achieved in @Query ?

Comment: put your code please

Comment: This isn't really Spring Data JPA related, Open JPA chokes on that... The query is passed, as is, to your JPA provider. However I wonder if that is even possible in JPA...

Comment: @NitinDandriyal - trying to do order by on value using division between 2 columns ( x / y ).

Comment: Yes, I get that but I think your query will run without brackets as well

Comment: No, it does not. In that case it is not able to parse the " / "  symbol.

Comment: What if you re-write your query as `select st, st.totalMargin / st.totalRevenue as ratio from Strategy st where st.unId= ?1 order by ratio desc`

Answer (score 0):

In your Strategy object, u can add a getter :

```
public double getMarginRatio() {
  return (this.totalMargin / this.totalRevenue);
}
```

then, your order by statement will become "`order by st.marginRatio`"

Comment: Thanks Tristan, I tried this. This does not work. It expects one of the existing column names.

Answer (score 0):

Yes with nativeQuery

```
@Query(value = "select st from STRATEGY st where st.unId= ?1 order by ( st.totalMargin / st.totalRevenue ) desc", nativeQuery = true)
```